# I want a shell scripts to delete ALL files in a dir, BUT NOT dir

Tags: files, deleted-files

I am doing this

```
rm -r users/path/DIR/ *
```

and it deletes `DIR`.

I want to delete all contents of `DIR` without deleting `DIR`.

I also want to execute this shell script while being in root dir.

ANSWERED:   rm -rf   instead of rm -r

Comment: Oh... Take care with this `rm -r users/path/DIR/ *`! There is a space before the `*` That means it deletes **recusively** all that is in the current directory + the `DIR`

Answer (score 0):

You have a space between `users/path/DIR/` and `*`. The correct command is :

```
rm -r users/path/DIR/*
```

If you also want to delete hidden files run :

```
rm -r users/path/DIR/* users/path/DIR/.*
```

Comment: i tried what u said and i get this 


rm: cannot remove `/users/path/DIR/*': No such file or directory